Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. events=0x9, fd=466
I am having a problem when running the kivy app on android device. It works fine when running the code on my computer but when running it on android device it crash. So here's the scenario. I am using zbarcam for scanning barcodes. Here is some codes of my python file
    def scanned_qr(self, instance, symbols):
        # Decoding Scanned BarCodes

        if symbols:
            # Assume only one symbol is scanned at a time
            symbol = symbols[0]
            decoded_symbol = symbol.data.decode('utf-8')
            print(decoded_symbol)
            # Displaying symbol in TextField
            display_text = self.root.get_screen('newevent').ids.rn_data
            display_text.text = decoded_symbol

        screen_manager.current = 'newevent'

        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.stop_zbarcam(), 2)

    def stop_zbarcam(self):

        zbarcam = self.root.get_screen('qrscan').ids.zbarcam
        if zbarcam is not None:
            zbarcam.stop()
            # Release camera device
            camera = zbarcam.ids.xcamera
            if camera._camera:
                camera._camera = None

here is my kv file:
MDScreen:
name:'qrscan'
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ZBarCam:
        id: zbarcam
        on_symbols:
            app.scanned_qr(*args)

it works perfectly fine if i run this on my computer however, here is the problem i encounter in my android device using adb locat:
04-24 13:58:27.844  3948  3987 I CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client org.test.myapp API Level 1

04-24 13:58:27.844  2809  3120 I CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client org.test.myapp API Level 1
04-24 13:58:27.845  1426  1445 I CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client org.test.myapp API Level 1
04-24 13:58:27.845  3597  3627 I CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client org.test.myapp API Level 1
04-24 13:58:42.523   756  9236 I CameraService: updateProxyDeviceState: notifyCameraState for Camera ID 0,  newState 2, facing 0, clientName org.test.myapp, apiLevel 1
04-24 13:58:42.524  1426  1443 I CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client org.test.myapp API Level 1
04-24 13:58:42.524  2809  4100 I CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client org.test.myapp API Level 1
04-24 13:58:42.524  3948  4026 I CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client org.test.myapp API Level 1
04-24 13:58:42.524  3597  3627 I CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client org.test.myapp API Level 1
04-24 13:58:42.542  8746  9194 I python  :    File "/home/jmcjaythan/Desktop/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/app.py", line 956, in run
04-24 13:58:42.543  8746  9194 I python  :    File "/home/jmcjaythan/Desktop/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp
04-24 13:58:42.544  8746  9194 I python  :    File "/home/jmcjaythan/Desktop/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 339, in mainloop
04-24 13:58:42.545  8746  9194 I python  :    File "/home/jmcjaythan/Desktop/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 379, in idle
04-24 13:58:42.545  8746  9194 I python  :    File "/home/jmcjaythan/Desktop/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/clock.py", line 733, in tick
04-24 13:58:42.546  8746  9194 I python  :    File "/home/jmcjaythan/Desktop/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/clock.py", line 776, in post_idle
04-24 13:58:42.550  8746  9194 I python  :    File "/home/jmcjaythan/Desktop/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/core/camera/camera_android.py", line 159, in _update
04-24 13:58:42.551  8746  9194 I python  :    File "/home/jmcjaythan/Desktop/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/core/camera/camera_android.py", line 166, in _copy_to_gpu
04-24 13:58:42.560  8746  9194 I python  :    File "/home/jmcjaythan/Desktop/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 60, in custom_callback
04-24 13:58:42.561  8746  9194 I python  :    File "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/qrscan.kv", line 10, in 
04-24 13:58:43.208   972  1218 W InputDispatcher: channel '51937f3 org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9, fd=466
04-24 13:58:43.208   972  1218 E InputDispatcher: channel '51937f3 org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
I tried to remove this and compiled again to apk
if zbarcam is not None:
        zbarcam.stop()

it works, everytime there is a scanned codes it will display to my screen where there is a textfield.
however when i added back the zbarcam.stop() the app crashes. BTW I am using screen managers. I am using kivy 2.3.0 and kivymd 1.1.1
